# Run php function on button click

Tags: php, function, button, onclick, submit-button

I want to run a php function on button click. for eg :

```
<input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="RUN"  onclick="<?php echo testfun(); ?>" /><br/>

<?php

function testfun()
{
   echo "Your test function on button click is working";
}

?>
```

My question is that when I do this I don't get the expected output I was looking for. Please give me the best solution for this to run a php function on button click whether it is a simple `button` or `submit`.

Comment: You can`t do this, php is a scripting language. If you want click events try Javascript

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried the code of William, Thanks brother.

but it's not working as a simple button I have to add form with method="post". Also I have to write submit instead of button.

here is my code below..

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>
</form>

<?php

function testfun()
{
   echo "Your test function on button click is working";
}

if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
   testfun();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Do this:

```
<input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>

<?php

function testfun()
{
   echo "Your test function on button click is working";
}
if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
   testfun();
}
?>
```

Comment: will it work, without wrapped by a `form` tag which has `method ="POST"` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="home.php?click=1" class="btn">Click me</a>
<?php 
  if($_GET['click']){
    doSomething();
  }
?>
```

But is better to use JS and with ajax to call function!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isset()`.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" />

</form>

<?php

function testfun()
{
   echo "Your test function on button click is working";
}

if(isset($_POST('submit')))
{
   testfun();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a javascript function. If you want to call a PHP function, you have to use for example a form:

```
    <form action="action_page.php">
       First name:<br>
       <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
       <br>
       Last name:<br>
       <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

(Original Code from: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

So if you want do do a  asynchron call, you could use 'Ajax' - and yeah, that's the Javascript-Way. But I think, that my code example is enough for this time :)

Answer (score -1):

No Problem You can use `onClick()` function easily without using any other interference of language,

```
<?php
echo '<br><Button onclick="document.getElementById(';?>'modal-wrapper2'<?php echo ').style.display=';?>'block'<?php echo '" name="comment" style="width:100px; color: white;background-color: black;border-radius: 10px; padding: 4px;">Show</button>';
?>
```

Comment: Hello, the button shows... but I don't get the application so the solution for the question. Thank you if you add it.