# add to cart button adds value on database when clicked

Tags: php, html, jscript

i want my "add to cart" button to put value on my database table named "items" on column named "status"

i tried the "on click" thing but it doesn't work

```
 <a ref="#" class="button button-danger button-circle button-sim">
     <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" on click=""></i>
 </a>
```

And when clicked I want it to show an alert that it is now in their cart.

I know the first line of code has wrong spelling, cant post the question without changing it

Comment: Can you show us the php and js code? How are we suppose to answer your question with just a html sample?

Comment: i don't have codes for that, I only tried adding the codes in another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824360/run-php-function-on-button-click/32824524

Comment: I don't have the codes and I don't know how to do it, that's why I'm asking. I'm new to programming but I really want to learn.